# How should I understand this Kafka Avro Schema Registry Error - Error retrieving Avro unknown schema?

Tags: apache-kafka, schema

My kafka consumer sometime throws this kind of error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro unknown schema for id 42

Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Unrecognized token 'upstream': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')

at [Source: (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream); line: 1, column: 10]; error code: 50005
      at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:293)
      at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:352)
      at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:660)
      at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:642)
```

It is unclear to me what the root cause of this.

Is this because the consumer cannot access to schema registry url (something like authentication error) or this is because the kafka message is bad (not compatible with the schema in the registry)?

What does the "Unrecognized token 'upstream'" mean ?

Comment: Could you please share avro schema file used along with schema registry configuration

Comment: @shasr the 'upstream' is not contained in the schema.

Comment: It seems that there should be also a code added to this `RestClientException` that may help in identification of the issue. One thing to check is that there is no mismatch between versions of schema registry and the library You are using.

Comment: @DominikWosiński Thanks for your help Dominik, RestClientException is a third party lib and I am not able to modify its code or there is a way to add a code to a third party lib? There shouldn't be any mismatch because this happens occasionally. If there is, I should be able to see this error every time.

Comment: Yeah, I know that it's third party lib but if You are using Confluent Avro Schema Registry, whenever this exception is created there is also an `error` code assigned to it, which may help in verifying what might be the cause for that. Also, I would advise checking the logs in the Schema Registry if You have access there. What is more, if You enable logging level DEBUG, client will log all requests by default so it may help too.

Comment: @DominikWosiński you are right, I updated the above by adding stack trace, which contains an error code 50005. Do you think it is due to authentication issue or something else ?

Comment: Nah, It's assigned by the client if it receives the `JsonProcessingException` from the server. I think You need to check the exact request that is sent by the client as this is the source of the problem.